# How long will my circuit run normally if its battery level reduces?

Tags: circuit-analysis, battery-operated

I am using a 3.7V battery for my circuit. What will happen when the battery level reduces to 3V, 2.5V, etc? Won't some of my components stop working at these low voltages?

Comment: Can you describe your circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some may, some may not, it depends on what components are in use.

You usually design a circuit so that it can operate over the range of voltages that the chosen battery or supply will deliver.

Most ICs will specify a minimum voltage at which they will work in their data sheet. However, beware, even when an individual IC is 'working', some of its parameters, so current drive, bandwidth etc, may be less at a lower rail voltage than the typicals you hoped for. Your system design has to allow for the lower performance at extremes of voltage.

If you have a circuit that works only over a small range of voltage, power it from a regulator that can accept the voltage variation from the battery. A switch mode regulator will make best use of the energy in the battery.

Answer (score 0):

> im using a 3.7V battery for my circuit. what will happen when the battery level reduces to 3V, 2.5V, etc? won't some of my components stop working at these low voltages?

Diodes work good at 0.7 volts. Red LEDs can work at 1.7 volts. BJTs can work at 0.7 volts. Capacitors and resistors don't care what the supply is and neither do inductors. Some MOSFETs will struggle but a lot will be fine.

A lot of op-amps (modern ones) will work at 1.8 volts. You've got plenty of options on stuff that work below 2.5 volts. A lot of MCUs will work below 2.5 volts.

It's all down to good design and what your circuit is intended to do.

If you expect to drive a 12V motor then clearly you are going to have problems.